# MultiThreading with for loops in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

Alright so i have been trying to run a for loop that runs 60 times. In this for loop i am using Thread.sleep(2000); to ping a server. I want to do this 10 times for this thread but for a separate loop through the for loop. In the mean time i want another 6 threads running doing 10 of their own so this hole process is sped up and completed in around 12 seconds.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    //I am starting a new thread here. 
}

@Override
public void run() {
//THIS is where i want a each thread to be doing 10 each to speed up the process.
  for(int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    //Pinging server.
    Thread.sleep(2000L);
    //Gets info from server here. That is why there is a 2 second delay.
  }
}
```

I am sorry if this is hard to understand but i tried setting this out in the simplest way possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: do u mean u want to ping and get a reply 10 times in each pass of the for loop? That means u would have 600 pings for each thread and for 6 threads it would be 3600 pings in total.

Comment: Basically i want to allocate each of the 6 threads to 10 parts each of the for loop that runs 60 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get You right, You are not depending on the results, right? Here is a quick handdraft made out of the code:

```
Thread[] t = new Thread[6];
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
   t[i] = new Thread() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
          //Pinging server.
          Thread.sleep(2000L);
          //Gets info from server here. That is why there is a 2 second delay.
        }
       }
     };
     t[i].start();
}

Thread.sleep(longEnough);
```

This is the cheapest variant for kicking off threads, but beware, it is not professional! You should at least loop over the thread array to call join() on them in order to wait long enough instead of using a time constant.

If You want to do serious threading please consider using Java's ExecutorService (see http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html#threadpools) or ForkJoin of Java 7 (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html)

Comment: Thanks for the extra sources you've linked, that should help a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

In your initial for loop, instead of creating Threads, you should be creating Callable instances.  Add these into a List, create an Executor, and pass the List to the Executor (FixedThreadPool for example).  Then execute the Executor and they'll run in parallel. After all these hints, Ill leave the implementation to you since this looks sneakingly like a homework question.